# Python mysql timestamp insert does not work but will work in mysql client

Tags: python, mysql, timestamp

When in the mysql client the following query works perfectly:

```
 INSERT  INTO VOLUMES (VOLUMEID, NAME, TYPE, SERVERID,SIZE, DEVICENAME, CREATIONDATE) VALUES ('vol-b67d73b7', 'TBC','gp2', 'i-7d445a89', '8', '/dev/sda1', '2014-11-24T07:40:37.921Z');
```

However when I use the same query in my python script I get the following error:

```
1265: Data truncated for column 'CREATIONDATE' at row 1
```

Here is the python code:

```
try:
  db = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
   cursor = db.cursor()

  for volume in volumes:
    ins_stmt = ("INSERT  INTO VOLUMES (VOLUMEID, NAME, TYPE, SERVERID,"
            "SIZE, DEVICENAME, CREATIONDATE) VALUES ('{0}', 'TBC',"
            "'{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{4}', '{5}');")
    to_execute = ins_stmt.format( volume.id, volume.type,
            volume.attach_data.instance_id, volume.size,
            volume.attach_data.device, volume.create_time)
    cursor.execute(to_execute)

except mysql.connector.Error as err:
  if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
    print("Something is wrong with your user name or password")
  elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
    print("Database does not exists")
  else:
    print(err)
else:
  db.close()
```

I don't understand what could be wrong. Can anyone help?

Comment: You shouldn't use `str.format` for interpolating values into queries, it's a huge [SQL injection](http://xkcd.com/327/) risk. Take a look at [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html) for examples of how it should be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use *SQL parameters* and have the database adapter handle quoting for you:

```
ins_stmt = ("INSERT  INTO VOLUMES (VOLUMEID, NAME, TYPE, SERVERID,"
        "SIZE, DEVICENAME, CREATIONDATE) VALUES (?, 'TBC',"
        "%s, %s, %s, %s, %s);")
params = (volume.id, volume.type,
        volume.attach_data.instance_id, volume.size,
        volume.attach_data.device, volume.create_time)
cursor.execute(to_execute, params)
```

Not only does this ensure that you don't run into problems with pre-existing quoting characters in your strings, it also avoids SQL injection attacks (where a user crafts data that breaks out of the quoting and issues additional SQL statements you did not intent to allow). Don't let Little Bobby Tables get you!

[image: Little Bobby Tables comic from XKCD]

Next, make sure your timestamps are in a format that [MySQL supports](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html); your timestamp appears to have a 3-digit fraction and a timezone specifier; MySQL 5.6.4 and up appears to expect a 6 digit fraction, a space instead of the `T`, and no timezones, so perhaps you should remove that portion from your `volume.create_time` string:

```
params = (volume.id, volume.type,
          volume.attach_data.instance_id, volume.size,
          volume.attach_data.device,
          volume.create_time.replace('T', ' ').partition('.')[0])
```

The message you see is telling you that MySQL won't accept the date as formatted. Your MySQL client is either only issuing a *warning* (instead of an error), or it is configured to allow invalid dates ([`ALLOW_INVALID_DATES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_allow_invalid_dates) is set). If a warning was set you need to ask MySQL for the warning with `show warnings` in the client.

Comment: @user1658296: Did you try and print what `params` contains? Perhaps your `volume.create_time` value is not quite what you think it is.

Comment: @user1658296: but you just claimed the format worked for you in the MySQL client. Looking at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html the `Z` at the end is not supported, and the fraction should be *6 digits*, not 3.

Comment: @user1658296: it could be that you tested with an older MySQL server when you used the client? Only 5.6.4 and up support fractions anyway; in older MySQL servers the fractional portion is discarded instead.

Comment: That's what I found so odd. I tested it on the very same server. I will try formatting the datetime correctly now.

Comment: @user1658296: Found out more about MySQL and date formatting. Your format is indeed incorrect, but the MySQL client has either been configured to ignore invalid dates, or you are ignoring a warning that is being issued; run `show warnings;` to show the warnings issued, it should show the same message.

Comment: Thanks I corrected the timestamp, and now I no more problems.